# How to get an Atari game console to work on a flat screen TV?

Tags: hardware, monitor, atari-2600

My TV does not have a cable in for my Atari. Is there a device that converts from RF coax or UHF to HDMI or other common ports found on flat screens? Is there a aftermarket console that can play the game by the cartridge or use a medium like a VCR?

[image]

Comment: I believe that some capture units may be able to do this, though unsure which.

Comment: Would a cable box work? Back in the day we used a VCR, but nothing has inputs anymore...

Comment: @Mazura can you show me how it is used on a vcr in an answer? This is good,

Comment: I'm pretty sure they stopped making VCR's before HDMI came out, so that's moot. A VCR could get you from RF to RCA, but then you have to get from RCA to HDMI somehow. The key piece of tech, which you won't find in a dumpster, is a device with an input (of any kind) and an HDMI out. E.g., a cable box (but not sure that even works)

Comment: It's pretty self explanatory if you can actually get a VCR to work on the TV. That's the new hard part. That would mean you have RF or RCA inputs on the TV, which I doubt. S-Video can be dealt with using a dongle, but component-in (green red blue) is about useless. What inputs you got?

Comment: @Mazura VGA RCA S-cable HDMI. Whats a dongle?

Comment: [How to Connect Your Old Videogame System](https://atariage.com/howto/connect.html) – atariage.com | A dongle is just an adapter with a short cord; most plain old S-Video adapters are too long IMO which can put extra stress on the circuit broad.

Comment: Adding my vote in support of reopening this, as this can objectively and definitively be answered with the right adapter type, without going into details of specific name brands or recommendations.

Comment: @Gigazelle Answerability is an incredibly poor metric to use for reopening questions.  It's asking for a product.  That's off-topic, regardless of whether or not we can answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *are* devices that can "tune" into RF Analog signal and convert it to HDMI, for example, [this one on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01JSODO2O).

It's kinda expensive though if you're going to use it *just* for playing Atari 2600 games...

Answer (score 1):

Do you specifically need to play the original cartridges or are you OK with just the games?

Atari is releasing a modernized console-like system called the [Ataric VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_VCS_(2018_console)).  It's not out yet, but you can read the details on the Wiki page.

Comment: ideally i would like to have the Atari and cartilages on view

Comment: You can just display them.  Getting the originals to work is very, very expensive compared to getting an emulator.